# Generation of the different string combination based on predefined string and dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, combinations

I'm trying to write function which will give me all possible combination of the given string based on predefined dictionary. Assume the example:

```
dict = {'a':'á', 'a':'ä', 'y':'ý'}
string = "antony"
word_combination(string, dict) #desired function
```

And expected result should be:

```
["antony", "ántony", "äntony", "ántoný", "äntoný", "antoný"]
```

i.e. we created all possible combination of the defined *string* doing replacement based on the defined *dictionary*.
Any suggestions/tips how to do it, please?

Comment: your dict is invalid, dict cannot have duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution after turning your dictionary to a valid one:

```
import itertools

d = {'a':['á','ä'], 'y':['ý']}
string = "Anthony"

# if since each char can be replaced with itself, add it to the list of 
# potential replacements. 
for k in d.keys():
    if k not in d[k]:
        d[k].append(k)

res = []
for comb in [zip(d.keys(), c) for c in itertools.product(*d.values())]:
    s = string
    for replacements in comb:
        s = s.replace(*replacements)
    res.append(s)
```

The result is:

```
['ánthoný', 'ánthony', 'änthoný', 'änthony', 'anthoný', 'anthony']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Just for completeness: in correct solution rows "for replacements in comb:" and "s = string" should be swapped.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Thanks. Updated the solution.